# In Data Studio Filter Data to < Current Hour

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I do a lot of day-of reporting and one of the things I'm trying to do is compare today's performance to another day. The trouble is I'm trying to comp. to that day to the last full hour. Essentially filter out all data in that comp day that happened after the last completed hour.

I've accomplished this in Tableau but I'd like for this report to be done in Data Studio. Is there a way of using functions to create a custom metric that returns the current hour? If I could get that I could easily use it as a filter for my report.

Thanks for any help.

Here's what the solution looks like in tableau:

```
IF [Session Hour (int)] <= [Current Hour]
THEN
[Revenue GA]
END
```

And:

```
DATEPART('hour', Now())-4
```

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

I was able to filter to the current hour by
a) making a calculated field to figure out the minutes difference between now and the data

```
minutes_before_now = datetime_diff(current_datetime(),the_time,MINUTE)
```

[image: Field name and formula for minutes difference]

and b) filtering the data where this field was < 60
[image: Filter set up and values]

Answer (score -2):

My advice would be to create a filter inside a date range, p.e.

[image: filter]

[image: filter2]

And then you can choose the comparison range within the primary date range.

That's what I'd do, if I understood your question.

Comment: That does not solve `current hour` you just used a fixed number.